# Search all user with user meta and meta value in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I am trying to implement search functionality to get list of all users with same meta key and value.Created form and on submission of form passing data from form to  custom template page for result but not  getting user details with same meta key and meta value.

```
$subject_name = $_POST['sub'];
   global $wpdb; 
       $user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'addedsubjects_detail', 'meta_value' => $subject_name ) ); 
        $userss = $user_query->get_results(); 
       if (!empty($users)) { 
           echo '</p> <ul>'; 
           foreach ($userss as $usrer){ 
               echo '</p> <li>' . $usrer->display_name . '</li> <p>'; 
           } echo '</ul> <p>'; 
       } else { 
           echo 'No users found'; 
       }
```

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with your strategy or your query. You have a few typos in your code - `$userss` and `$usrer`.

You don't need to include `global $wpdb;` based on this snippet alone, maybe you need it for something else.

The variable names `$userss` and `$usrer` have been replaced with `$users` and `$user` in the code below which works as intended.

```
$subject_name = $_POST['sub'];
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'addedsubjects_detail', 'meta_value' => $subject_name ) );
$users = $user_query->get_results();
if (!empty($users)) {
    echo '</p> <ul>';
    foreach ($users as $user){
        echo '</p> <li>' . $user->display_name . '</li> <p>';
    } 
    echo '</ul> <p>';
} else {
   echo 'No users found';
}
```

Comment: I set the meta data on a user and ran the code and it worked. Based on the number of typos in the original code, I have to ask if you verified `addedsubjects_detail` was set for a user. `echo get_user_meta(  $id, 'addedsubjects_detail', true);`

Comment: actually my usermeta is in form of json and other in string so thats why its doesn't able to match.Same works for single value form meta key.How can i get it from json and string format

Comment: How about using a regex? `'meta_compare' => 'REGEXP'` and `'meta_value' => '^.*' . $subject_name . '.*'`